# To open Netbeans error

Tags: 14.04, netbeans

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and installed netbeans 8.0.2 but it crashed so I removed and reinstalled. But I can't open that one and I get:

> An instance of the program can't access specified user directory. This is a serious problem that may prevent the program to function properly. Make sure /root/.netbeans/8.0.2 is writable.

However, I'm able to open netbeans using the terminal command:

```
/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: can you run `ls - l /root/.netbeans/8.0.2` ? to see if the folder is writable

Comment: You run Netbeans as `root`?!

Answer (score 2):

If you installed netbeans using the .sh script then I suppose you  used **sudo**

i.e
`sudo ./netbeans.sh`

However graphical user interface programs are not run(just by clicking) with root privileges on ubuntu so thats why you are having that problem. If you are not comfortable accessing you current installation using terminal get into **/usr/local/netbeans-installation-folder and run the .sh uninstall script**. Then install the program again without using the sudo command like

`./netbeans.sh` (remeber to make it read/write using `sudo chmod +x netbeans.sh`)

## Update

If you installed it without using sudo(root) and you still have this problem
run

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name /home/your_user_name/.netbeans
```